# Create custom DialogPreference programmatically

Tags: android, dialog, preference

How can I create the dialog preference in code ?

```
        MyDialog dialog=new MyDialog(getActivity() );
        dialog.setTitle("asd");
        dialog.setKey("key");
        dialog.getDialog().show();
```

This is in my xml file, and it works fine when called prom preference screen

```
<!-- Custom Dialog -->
    <com.pak.asd.MyDialog
        android:key="key" android:title="title"
        android:dialogTitle="title"
        android:negativeButtonText="no"
        android:positiveButtonText="yes" android:dialogMessage="message" />
```

this is my class

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogPreference {
    private Context c;

    public MyDialog(Context c)
    {
    //is null correct ?
        super(oContext,null);       
        this.oContext = oContext;
    }

    public MyDialog(Context c, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(c, attrs);        
        this.c = c;
    }

}
```

Comment: I see that the constructor is added now for API21, but will it throw an exception if we call `super(c,null)` in older platforms. What happened for your.

Answer (score 0):

`DialogPreference` has no `DialogPreference (Context context)` constructor, so, why do you define a `MyDialog(Context c)` constructor? Usually, you don't need that constructor, just the second one.

I have never used `DialogPreference` before, but you should be able to create your custom class the same way as the base one.

Comment: What have you tried? Look for DialogPreference uses in Java code, I have never used it. Any example would fit for your extended class, don't worry for it.